# XGBoost callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, xgboost

I'm following [this](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/examples/callbacks.html) example to understand how callbacks work with xgboost.

I modified the code to run without gpu_hist and use hist only (otherwise I get an error):

`'tree_method': 'hist'`

I'm facing two problems:

1. The matplotlib plot opens but does not update and shows not-responding.
2. I attempted to write a custom print statement. The statements are printed only after code execution is completed.

Note that if I stop in the debugger and manually execute line by line everything works as expected.

My guess is I need to somehow force a "draw"?

Any help solving either problem is appreciated. Below are my system specs:

- OS: Windows 10
- python: 3.10.9
- xgboost version: 1.7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plots and console writes were not updating because execution was too fast.
In the example I added a pause the plot with

```
self.fig.canvas.draw()
plt.pause(0.01)
```

The seconds in pause had to be "tuned" to something small but acceptable.